# React Hooks Responsive Sidebar

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, react-sidebar

I want to develop a responsive sidebar in React. I took https://startbootstrap.com/template/simple-sidebar template as an example.I can use it in block1:

Block 1:

```
function App() {
 
  useEffect(() => {
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div class="d-flex" id="wrapper">
      <div class="bg-light border-right" id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <div class="sidebar-heading">Start Bootstrap</div>
        <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">
            Dashboard
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light border-bottom">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" id="menu-toggle">
            Toggle Menu
          </button>
        </nav>

        <div class="container-fluid"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I tried to convert it to pure react, page is not working successfully.Some elements are losing.

Block 2:

```
function App() {
  const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false);
  const className = isActive ? "toggled" : "d-flex";

  const handleToggle = () => {
    setActive(!isActive);
  };

  return (
    <div class={className} id="wrapper">
      <div class="bg-light border-right" id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <div class="sidebar-heading">Start Bootstrap</div>
        <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">
            Dashboard
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light border-bottom">
          <button
            class="btn btn-primary"
            id="menu-toggle"
            onClick={() => handleToggle()}
          >
            Toggle Menu
          </button>
        </nav>

        <div class="container-fluid"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

App.css

```
#wrapper {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin-left: -15rem;
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: margin 0.25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: margin 0.25s ease-out;
  transition: margin 0.25s ease-out;
}

#sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-heading {
  padding: 0.875rem 1.25rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

#sidebar-wrapper .list-group {
  width: 15rem;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
  min-width: 100vw;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  margin-left: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #sidebar-wrapper {
    margin-left: 0;
  }

  #page-content-wrapper {
    min-width: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }

  #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    margin-left: -15rem;
  }
}
```

I could not find the place I missed.
Can u help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing this:

```
const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false);
const className = isActive ? "toggled" : "d-flex";
```

like so:

```
const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false);
const [className, setClassName] = useState('d-flex');

useEffect(() => {
    if (isActive) setClassName('toggled');
    else setClassName('d-flex');
}, [isActive]);
```

Comment: thanks for answer but all elements are losing when click on button.Is it about css.(this line `#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper `) . when I change wrapper class, Should I change other element class

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve this by doing this:

```js
const [open, setOpen] = useState("");
  const hide = () => setOpen("translateX(100%)");
  const show = () => setOpen("translateX(0)");
```

And then pass the props from the styled component class to the sidebar container:

```js
const SidecartContainer = styled.div`
  transform: ${(props) => props.transform};
`;
```

```js
const SideCart = (props) => {
  return (
    <SidecartContainer transform={props.transform} open={props.open}>
      <ExitButton open={props.open} onClick={props.onClick}>
```